# How to select nested radiobutton with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="myform0">    
    <fieldset>                  
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionHere2" value="2">Yes</label>
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionHere1" value="1">No</label>            
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionHere3" value="3">Not decided</label>                        
    </fieldset>                 
</form>
<form class="form-inline" id="myform1">    
    <fieldset>                  
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionHere2" value="2">Yes</label>
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionHere1" value="1">No</label>            
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionHere3" value="3">Not decided</label>                        
    </fieldset>                 
</form>
```

What I want to do is be able to programatically select a radio button in each group.  Everything I tried so far has not worked.  Thoughts?

Edit:

This selects all of them:
    $("input[name=optionsRadios][value=1]").attr('checked', 'checked');

I am just looking to select a specific one.

Comment: u can't use same ids for fields dude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check each first radio button use the following code:

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).find(":radio:first").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Or shorter:

```
$("form").find(":radio:first").prop("checked", true);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Also check you have elements with the same IDs (e.g. `optionHere1`, `optionHere2`, etc).

**ID's should be unique!**

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mAeTa/

---

**UPDATE.** This will also work fine:

```
$("form").find(":radio[name='optionsRadios'][value='1']").prop("checked", true);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mAeTa/1/

Comment: Keep in mind that using `:first-of-type` instead of `:first` and `input[type="radio"]` instead of `:radio` will be faster in browsers that support `querySelectorAll()`. I don't think that this will be a *big* performance hit, but it's nice to remember. http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/